# PHP PDO - Show a particular row and column

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, row, fetch

I need to show some particular Row and Column of DataBase

```
// my query
$products = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM products");
$products->execute();
$row_products = $products->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$totalRows_products=$products->rowCount();
```

This show the 1st product

```
echo $row_products->name;
echo $row_products->value;`
```

But i need to show some particular Row
I cant use DO or WHILE because it can not be sequential
Something like this, but it dont work:

```
My 3rd product is: <?php echo $row_products[2]->name; ?>
and my 6th product is: <?php echo $row_products[5]->name; ?>
```

Comment: What is your exact requirement?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `->fetchAll` instead of `->fetch`.

Comment: Some explanation of this answer would have been helpful to this questioner and also others that find this answer later

Answer (score 0):

You can get all your records by replacing `$products->fetch` by `$products->fetchAll` :

```
<?php
$products = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM products");
$products->execute();
$row_products = $products->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$totalRows_products = count($row_products):

// $row_products contains all the rows. You can even loop :
for ($i = 0; $i < $totalRows_products; ++$i)
{
    echo 'Row n° '.($i + 1).' : ';
    echo $row_products[$i]->name.' '.$row_products[$i]->value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks FHanisch and Heru-Luin for your answer

using `fetchAll` was not enough.

I have to change `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`to `PDO::FETCH_OBJ`

```
<?php
$products = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM products");
$products->execute();
$row_products = $products->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$totalRows_products=$products->rowCount();

echo 'My 6th product: '.$row_products[5]->name;
?>
```